# iPhone App on iPad in Landscape mode does not respond any touches at launch

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibutton, touch

I create the iPhone app that working in Landscape mode only.
It works well on iPhone.
On iPad, `UIButtons` does not respond any touches at launch although `UIButtons` are displayed correctly.
After Tapping 2x button, `UIButtons` works well.

why?

This is occurred in the process below.

1. Create new project with Single View Application Template.
2. Set Landscape Left and Landscape Right at Supported Interface orientation in TARGET.
3. Drag and Drop UIButton to View in Storyboard.
4. Run the app on iPad

After that,the apps launches on Landscape mode but `UIButtons` does not respond any touch.

Comment: Response here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445452/iphone-app-doesnt-respond-after-starting-in-landscape-orientation-on-ipad/18435717#18435717

Answer (score 0):

Try both of these things and it should work, I had this same issue. First make sure to set the root view controller in the App Delegate didFinishLaunching method. Second make sure to add the supported orientations in your view controller. The way to support orientations changed in iOS 6.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];   
    return YES;
}
```

To support landscape, add this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return  YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I wrote the code you posted but the situation didn't change. It worked when "Supported interface Orientations" in TARGETS set all off. It would be better not to set "Supported interface Orientations" ?