# iphone app doesn't respond after starting in landscape orientation on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

My iPhone app doesn't respond when launched on an iPad in landscape mode.

If it launches in portrait mode everything works fine. In landscape orientation nothing works until the app is rotated or the 1x 2x button is pressed.

I've tried debugging the app with breakpoints and stepping through the code but it shows that the app is running normally in the debug console.

Comment: In addition to the "supported interface orientations" work-around, Greg Hewgill and I also discovered that hiding the status bar during launch will fix it, too. Makes no sense to me, but they both work. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 12):

I have found that this is unique to iOS 6 devices, but if you remove all of the entries under "Supported interface orientation" in the app's plist, this problem goes away. Or if you check the "Hide during application launch" option for the "Status Bar" settings on the Summary screen of the Target settings, this also fixes it:

[image: hide during application launch]

There's no logical reason that I can see that either of these options *should* fix this bug, but they both do.

If you play around with the supported orientation settings in iOS 6, you can still programmatically control the permitted interface orientations via [`supportedInterfaceOrientations`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) (or in iOS 5, you can still use the[`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) method).

Comment: This seems like an iOS 6 bug and I have reported it via http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: This seems to work. Just be sure to show the status bar in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];`

Comment: One caveat with the "rotations" fix—it seems to cause issues with voiceover, not on initial launch, but switching out and back...voiceover thinks it's in portrait mode. I wound up going with the statusbar fix because our app is for the vision impaired, and that would have been a significant issue.

Comment: As an aside, bugreport was slow to acknowledge the issue (made me submit sample project even though I clearly explained how to reproduce the problem from blank-template project ... I've never had to do that with other bug reports), but they finally have acknowledged the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that just adding `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];` at the beginning of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function does the trick. No need to change the plist settings file.

Comment: +1. This worked for me and I think is a better solution. Certainly more robust, especially since you can put a comment there explaining why you made that choice.